# How Many Chim Chims do i need to kick to S Rank the Chim Chim part of the Area Ranking?

Tags: .hack-gu, .hack-gu-last-recode

When i go into an Area, to make sure i get as close to an S Rank as i can when i find the first Chim Chim generating action that gets more than 1 Chim Chim (kicking trees/activating steam vent on mine track, not places like the Wells) i generally do 5-10 activation before i continue on.

I'm wondering however how many Chim Chims i need to kick in order to S rank that item in the Area Ranking? if it's not a single amount for every area is there a way i can work it out?